# 6 ints in one EditText problems?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created (tired to...) a lottery program that asks the user for 6 number in one EditText and another "lucky number" in one more EditText, and if the numbers follow a few conditions they all will appear in the same TextView.
My problem is that I'm not sure I inserted the ints properly into the EditText, cause when I run the program it appears in the emulator but don't react to the things I write in the EditText. Can someone check my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

first class:

```
package com.example.hm195;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
class layout{
    public void layout(){
        Nums = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNums);
        Lnum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLuckyNum);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
    }
    EditText Nums, Lnum;
    Button btn;
    TextView Result;
}
class events {
    public void events(){
        l.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                n.valid();

            }
        });
    }
}
nums n;
layout l;
events e;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    l = new layout();
    e = new events();
}

}
```

second class:
    package com.example.hm195;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class nums {
/*int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g*/
MainActivity main;

 int a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
public void valid(){
     main.l.Nums.setText(a + "," + b + "," + c + "," + d + "," + e + "," + f);
     main.l.Lnum.setText(g);

    if ( a < 1 || a >37 || b < 1 || b >37 || c < 1 || c >37 || d < 1 || d >37 || e < 1 || e >37 || f < 1 || f >37) {
        Toast.makeText(main, "One or more of your six numbers is lower than 1 or higher than 37", 1).show();
        if (g < 1 || g > 7 ) {
        Toast.makeText(main, "Your lucky number is lower than 1 or higher than 7", 1).show();
        }
    }else {
        main.l.Result.setText(main.l.Nums.getText().toString() + " " + main.l.Lnum.getText().toString()); 
    }
}
}
```

xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNums"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etLuckyNum"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you getting some kind of error?Paste the logcat(if yes)

Comment: If you want to validate input to an EditText, you need to use `addTextChangedListener` and implement [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Comment: No error in the logcat. How (where) do I use addTextChangedListener?